# Section to keep growing with content on small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my sections increase with the content on small devices, I've added overflow: auto but that adds a scrollbar and makes the content scroll, i want the sections to have a specific height so I can center the content vertically by using flexbox, but without the overflow: auto, the sections hug each other and it gets messy.. Here is my code, I'll also add a codepen at the end, also I want to get the more button at the end of the Intro section, I tried everything from margin-top (it puts the tittle up and I want it centered vertically) I tried position: absolute but it doesn't work good on small screens..

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Required Meta tags-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Customs Fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Animate.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

  <!--Title-->
  <title>Peter Brezitski | Front-End Developer</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!--Navigation-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-company-red fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#intro">brezitski</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#about">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact-form">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--Intro-->
  <header id="intro">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row text-center ">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class="display-6"> I'm Peter, an upcoming Front-End Developer, gamer and lo-fi lover. </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a id="more" href="#about">More<br><i class="arrow down"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <hr>

  <!--About-->
  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mx-auto">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://scontent-sof1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/24294163_548521265481693_3086368752085107633_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&oh=b816b352c5e8cc5e61271a7569e0a560&oe=5C2C05F5">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="text-center info"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia saepe at rerum sed, tempora cupiditate, neque iure ab inventore porro eligendi, voluptatibus quisquam nihil qui asperiores nostrum libero provident quaerat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class=col-md-12>
          <p class="text-center what"> My skills:
            <p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p class="text-center">HTML5:
            <p>
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 95%">95%</div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p class="text-center">CSS3 / SaSS:
            <p>
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">75%</div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p class="text-center">Bootstrap:
            <p>
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">40%</div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p class="text-center">Javascript:
            <p>
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">20%</div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <hr>

  <!--Projects-->
  <section id="projects">
    <div class="container">

      <p class="text-center">Here are some of my projects:</p>

      <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-3 h-100">
            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-3 h-100">
            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-3 h-100">
            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-3 h-100">
            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-3 h-100">
            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-3 h-100">
            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <hr>

  <!--Contact-->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="form-cont">
        <form class="justify-content-center" id="contact-form">
          <form method="post">
            <p class="text-center">Do you want us to work together on a project? Leave me a message.</p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="txtName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="txtPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number *" value="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="txtMsg" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btnContact" value="Send Message" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <hr>

  <!--Social-->
  <footer id="social">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/writerofthedark"><span style="font-size: 25px;"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </span></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/writerofthedark/"><span style="font-size: 25px;"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </span></a>
          <a href="https://github.com/PeterBrezitski"><span style="font-size: 25px;"> <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
      </span></a>
          <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8202546/peter-brezitski"><span style="font-size: 25px;"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
      </span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap Required-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Custom Scripts-->
</body>

</html>
```

CSS - SASS:

```
body
  scroll-behavior: smooth
  height: 100%
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #fdfbfb 0%, #ebedee 100%)

p 
  font-size: 20px

section
  width: 100%
  height: 100%

/***HEADER***/

/*Brand*/
.navbar-brand 
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  font-size: 22px
  text-transform: uppercase
  color: #000000 !important


.navbar-brand:hover 
  color: #8a8a8a !important


/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar-nav 
  justify-content: flex-end
  flex-grow: 1


#navbarNavAltMarkup 
  align-items: flex-end
  justify-content: flex-end


#navbarNavAltMarkup a 
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  font-size: 14px
  text-transform: uppercase
  text-align: center
  color: #000000
  padding-right: 30px


#navbarNavAltMarkup a:link 


#navbarNavAltMarkup a:visited 


#navbarNavAltMarkup a:hover 
  border-bottom: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.4) 2px solid
  color: #8a8a8a


#navbarNavAltMarkup a:active 
  border-bottom: 2px solid
  color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.4) !important


#navbarNavAltMarkup a:focus 
  outline: none


.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler 
  border-color: #000000 !important
  font-size: 14px


.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon 
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,0,0)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important


.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler:focus 
  outline: none


.bg-company-red 
  background: transparent !important


.bg-company-red.scrolled 
  background: red !important


/***INTRO***/

#intro 
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  height: 90vh
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center

#intro h1 
  font-size: 32px

#intro a 
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  text-decoration: none
  color: black
  text-align: center
  display: block


#intro a:focus 
  outline: none  

#intro i 
  border: solid black
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0
  display: inline-block
  padding: 3px
  margin-bottom: 10px


#intro .down 
  transform: rotate(45deg)
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)


/***ABOUT***/

#about 
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  height: 90vh
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: center
  overflow: auto

#about img 
  border-radius: 50%
  width: 200px
  height: 200px


#about .info 
  margin: 60px 0 40px 0

#about p
  margin-top: 20px


/***Projects***/

#projects
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  height: 70vh
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  overflow: auto

#projects p
  padding-bottom: 50px


/***Contact***/

#contact
  font-family: "Gloria Hallelujah", cursive
  height: 70vh
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  overflow: auto

#form-cont
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center

#contact-form p
  padding-bottom: 50px

#contact-form
  width: 65%

#contact-form input
  border-radius: 10px

#contact-form textarea
  border-radius: 10px

#contact-form .btnContact
  border-radius: 10px
  border-color: #8a8a8a
  background-color: white
  color: black


#contact-form .btnContact:hover
  color: #8a8a8a
  cursor: pointer


/***Social***/

#social
  text-align: center

#social a 
  margin: 0px 10px 0px
  color: black

#social a:hover 
  color: #8a8a8a

#social a:focus 
  outline: none
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Sarithan/pen/pOmxPy?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to set specific height for a long content, its going to get overflowed and will display the scroll.

Try removing the height and the overflow attributes and it will let the content increase as the content grows in all device screens

```
https://codepen. io/anon/pen/wYvVMa
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it look a little more spacious if I can call it like that :D